# in and not in conditions multiple values not able with queryBuilder

Tags: jquery, validation, query-builder

this is my operator configurations (leaving other types for brevity )

```
operators: [
......
{type: 'in', nb_inputs: 1, multiple: true, apply_to: ['string', 'number', 'datetime']},
{type: 'not_in', nb_inputs: 1, multiple: true, apply_to: ['string', 'number', 'datetime']},
.......
],
```

'Category' filter is defined as

```
filters: [ {
id: 'category',
label: 'Category',
type: 'integer',
input: 'text',
values: {
1: 'Books',
2: 'Movies',
3: 'Music',
4: 'Tools',
5: 'Goodies',
6: 'Clothes'
},
operators: ['equal', 'not_equal', 'in', 'not_in', 'is_null', 'is_not_null']
}]
```

when I select 'in' as operator, I should be able to select multiple values but it is not letting me.

I mean, multiple values for in and not in conditions, data type double and int it is not allowing comma separator.

How can fix this ? Any idea please.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder/issues/341) and related issues, this problem was not solved yet. Only a workaround which pushes you to use the string field exists:

```
$('#builder').queryBuilder({
  filters: [
    {
      id: 'name',
      type: 'string',
      value_separator: ','
    }
  ]
});
```

It can be used with the version 2.4.0.

I will suggest a proper solution in this issue, you can follow it.

Regards.